# Static top navigation bar shows only after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nav bar that stays on top after scrolling, but if you hit the back button or a link like so ...com/index#downbelow the nav bar does not appear until you scroll.

How can I get the nav bar to show no matter what?

```
var num = 60; 

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menutop').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menutop').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://www.djaouida.com/index.php#aboutDjaouida)

Comment: here is some small example http://jsfiddle.net/kjd5bgwm/

Answer (score 0):

In url when there are # not triggered scroll events. therefore menu will not be fixed. Add this code to top of my-jquery.js

```
var ssss=$(document).scrollTop();
if(ssss>=60)  $('.menutop').addClass('fixed');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to always be fixed just remove that JavaScript and add the `fixed` class in the HTML.

`<nav class="menutop fixed">`

Answer (score 0):

You can run it once on DOM-ready, then bind to scroll:

```
var toggleMenuVisibility = function() {
  var num = 60; 
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
    $('.menutop').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.menutop').removeClass('fixed');
  }
}

$(function() {
  toggleMenuVisibility();
  $(window).bind('scroll', toggleMenuVisibility)
})
```